# Create account for service

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012, user-management

I am configuring a new server. The server is running Hudson that is going to copy some files from this server to another. The other server is a virtual machine. Both running Windows Server 2012. Hudson is started on server A with log on as "Local System". When I come to the copy phase it says "Access denied". Changing the log on to "Administrator" works. However, I guess this is bad. I do not have much experience with user management.

I tried to create a own hudson account on both servers A and B. I tried to log on as hudson account in the service-management but it doesn't start. How would you create an account for this particular service that has access to the shared folder on server B and can be used to start the service on server A? I guess I need two accounts with same username and password on server A and server B? The folder on Server B is shared with everyone and the guest account is enabled.

Comment: If serverA & ServerB are in a domain then you need to create a domain user and assign it appropriate rights to act as a service locally on each server.

Comment: They are not in a domain.

Comment: Yes, same username and pwd on both ends will work fine.

Comment: But my problem is that if I create a regular user and try to use the credentials of that user in the services manager as a "log on" it doesn't start. The user even gets the log as a service privilige.